# Datalist option validation required

Tags: javascript, html

Here is all the details

```
<form action="order.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<input type="text" list="From" name="From" autocomplete="off" placeholder="From Place">
<datalist id="From">
   <option value="Bankura Bus Stand">
   <option value="Bankura Hospital">
   <option value="Katjuridanga">
   <option value="Lokepur">
</datalist>
  <datalist id="To">
  <option value="Bankura Bus Stand">
  <option value="Bankura Hospital">
  <option value="Katjuridanga">
  <option value="Lokepur">
</datalist>
```

Javascript Validation

```
<script>
    function validate() {
       if (document.myForm.From.value == "") {
       alert("Please select From Place.!");
       return false;
       if (document.myForm.To.value == "") {
       alert("Please select From Place.!");
       return false;
</script>
```

Everything work fine, but i want only option value otherwise show alert error: when click on submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Book Now">
```

I want it by same script procedure... Thanks in advance

Comment: What is not working ? Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6t0y67n6/

Comment: every thing ok, but i want to block user define input... show "script alert item not in list.".. when user input other than list option

Answer (score 1):

Make `array` of all the option values and test the value of input with it.

- *The [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
  method creates a new Array instance from an `array-like` or iterable
  object.*
- *The [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
  method creates a `new array` with the results of calling a provided
  function on every element in this `array`.*
- The [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

```js
function validate() {
  var fromVal = document.myForm.From.value;
  var toVal = document.myForm.To.value;
  var from = document.getElementById('From');
  var to = document.getElementById('To');
  var optionValuesArrFrom = Array.from(from.options).map(function(elem) {
    return elem.value;
  });
  var optionValuesArrTo = Array.from(to.options).map(function(elem) {
    return elem.value;
  });
  if (fromVal == "") {
    alert("Please select From Place.!");
    return false;
  } else if (optionValuesArrFrom.indexOf(fromVal) === -1) {
    alert("item not in from list.!");
    return false;
  } else if (toVal == "") {
    alert("Please select To Place.!");
    return false;
  } else if (optionValuesArrTo.indexOf(toVal) === -1) {
    alert("item not in to list.!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="order.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
  <input type="text" list="From" name="From" autocomplete="off" placeholder="From Place">
  <datalist id="From">
    <option value="Bankura Bus Stand"></option>
    <option value="Bankura Hospital"></option>
    <option value="Katjuridanga"></option>
    <option value="Lokepur"></option>
  </datalist>
  <input type="text" list="To" name="To" autocomplete="off" placeholder="To Place">

  <datalist id="To">
    <option value="Bankura Bus Stand">
      <option value="Bankura Hospital">
        <option value="Katjuridanga">
          <option value="Lokepur">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" value="Book Now">
</form>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6t0y67n6/2/)

Comment: @gotnull, How would `select-input` look like if you have say 100 options ?

Comment: @ShariqueReza, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: @Rayon Good work. I wasn't understanding what OP was asking.

Comment: @gotnull, Your misunderstanding took few keystrokes from me! Never mind ;)

Comment: Hey @Rayon Edited my question can you help me with this

Comment: @ShariqueReza, Put another if condition!

Comment: i have tried but result is annoying :), can you do for me again

Comment: @ShariqueReza, Come on! Do some debugging! Show some efforts!

Comment: actually i am beginner.. and not known script language, just basics only, so please...